# Using job scheduler to repeat a job at specific time and then at specific intervals

Tags: android, job-scheduling

Aim: Build an app that reminds me to punch in at the machine. It will start at 8 am, repeat at 10 minute intervals. Every time, it will use TexttoSpeech to remind me to punch in.

The basic service and the activity is in place. How can JobScheduler be run at a specific hour and minute, and then run a job every 10 minutes till a specific time?

```
public class Util {
    public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
        ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, TestJobService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
    }
}

public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        Util.scheduleJob(context);
    }
}

public class TestJobService extends JobService {
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestVoice.class);
        getApplicationContext().startService(service);
        Util.scheduleJob(getApplicationContext()); // reschedule the job
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        return true;
    }
}

public class TestVoice extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextToSpeech tts;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener(){
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                    int result=tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    if(result==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA ||
                            result==TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
                        Log.e("error", "This Language is not supported");
                    }
                    else{
                        ConvertTextToSpeech("Have you punched in?");
                    }
                }
                else
                    Log.e("error", "Initilization Failed!");
            }
        });
    }
    private void ConvertTextToSpeech(String text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(text==null||"".equals(text))
        {
            text = "Content not available";
            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }else
            tts.speak(text+"is saved", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: "and then run a job every 10 minutes" - IMO not at all if you're on Nougat or higher and the device enters doze mode - I tried with both emulators and "real" devices, and the interval was sometimes just over ten and sometimes (10' tablet) close to 23 minutes.

Comment: Try using AutoMate instead. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en_GB&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dautomate+android&pcampaignid=APPU_1_vN2kWp21COaugAb1pJXgDw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can JobScheduler be run at a specific hour and minute, and then run a job every 10 minutes till a specific time?

It can't.

`JobScheduler` is intrinsically inexact. You provide general guidance for when jobs should run, and the jobs run when they run.

Particularly on Android 6.0+, there is nothing that will meet your requirements, with the exception of `setAlarmClock()` on `AlarmManager`. However, using this has UI repercussions, as it is designed for alarm clock apps. Using it for your desired purpose may also interfere with any actual alarm clock app on the device (in case this is a BYOD scenario, instead of a company-issued device). Also, `setAlarmClock()` is a one-shot event; you would need to call `setAlarmClock()` again as part of processing the previous event, to schedule when you want to get control again.

Comment: So the solution is to build a custom service?

Comment: @Droidzone: You are welcome to try having a foreground service, manually added to the battery optimization whitelist, and use some in-process timing solution (e.g., `ScheduledExecutorService`). However, this will require a continuous wake lock. The device's battery may not last a full work shift as a result. And, if this is a BYOD scenario, the people forced to use your app may express their displeasure with you in unfortunate ways. Hence, I would focus first on the `setAlarmClock()` approach, and see if that will suffice for your needs.

Comment: What if I use a persisting notification like some apps do? Will it still require a wakelock?

Comment: @Droidzone: "Will it still require a wakelock?" -- yes. If you are doing the timing yourself, you cannot allow the CPU to power down, ever.